# Display different results on different page/profiles

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I dont know if I lost the information in my brain, or if I never had it, but I have created a tweet so a user can follow other users.

The problem now is that every user display the same information. 
I Was trying to add WHERE `$_SESSION['uid']` to my query but that doesn't help do the trick.

Still shows the same info. 
Any tips ?

```
<?php 
    foreach(fetch_follotweets() as $tweet){ 
        echo $tweet['firstname']; 
        echo $tweet['lastname'];
        echo $tweet['username'];
        echo $tweet['date'];
        echo $tweet['profile_img'];
        $tweet['message'];
    }

    function fetch_follotweets(){
        global $db;
        $query = $db->query("   SELECT
                                  user.email,
                                  user.username,
                                  tweets.message,
                                  tweets.date,
                                  userdetails.profile_img,
                                  userdetails.firstname,
                                  userdetails.lastname,
                                  following.id,
                                  following.user_id,
                                  following.follow_id
                                FROM user
                                  JOIN userdetails
                                    ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
                                  JOIN tweets
                                    ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
                                  JOIN following
                                    ON following.follow_id
                                WHERE following.follow_id = tweets.user_id AND
                                user.id='{$_SESSION['uid']}
                                ORDER BY tweets.date DESC");
            $tweet = array();
        while(($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !==FALSE) { 
            $tweet[] = $row;
        }
        return $tweet;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do. Do you need all the records? Or are you displaying information when a user is logged in and user can see his information only?

Comment: @raheelshan this is a profile site, that show tweets that you are following. Just like twitter. I can enter different profile. But every profile should only show the tweets you are following. Now every profile is showing the same tweets.

Comment: i see you are not assigning the id to restrict results related to user

Comment: @raheelshan Thats the problem, when I add the user.id='{$_SESSION['uid']} it only returns empty results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `WHERE` clause, the `SQL` would get the details of all the users

Also, I think that the `JOIN` on `tweets` & `following` should be a `LEFT JOIN` ( to get the `records` even if none of them is present )

```
SELECT
  user.email,
  user.username,
  tweets.message,
  tweets.date,
  userdetails.profile_img,
  userdetails.firstname,
  userdetails.lastname,
  t.ids_of_users_followed
FROM 
  user
  JOIN userdetails
    ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( following.follow_id ) AS ids_of_users_followed
        following.user_id
      FROM
        following
      GROUP BY
        following.user_id
    ) as t ON ( t.user_id = user.id )
  JOIN tweets
    ON ( userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id OR FIND_IN_SET( tweets.user_id, t.ids_of_users_followed ) )
WHERE 
  user.id = :?    => Make sure to add the logged in user_id here
ORDER BY 
  tweets.date DESC
```

Comment: @Dymond I have updated the answer, there also seemed a problem with your JOIN's, please chk

Comment: The query looks fine to me, unless there's some other issue with your records!! (try firing it directly on the `SQL` console for particular user_id

Comment: Also, make sure to use `session_start()` within the page you are using it

Comment: well the query works fine. there is no problem with that. Is that I would like that every profile show it own query. 
like this.
user 1 -follow user 2 . on user 1s profile you only see the tweets of user 2.

Now every profile show everything that the users follow.

Comment: I dont think your requirements are clear to me, is it that, on user1's homepage, you wish to show a list of tweets of user1 as well as user2 (if user 1 fellow's user 2) ?

Comment: exactly :) But now every registered user see what user 1 is following, own their on profile. like it was their own.
Was thinking about an if else statement ! like if(empty(follow.follow_id){ you dont follow any one...}

Comment: try the updated the query, there could be syntax errors in it ;p

Comment: I will my fried, but I think i got a solution by using 
<?php foreach(fetch_follotweets($_GET['uid']) as $tweet){?> and then call the id from the query.